# The sock. connect timeout was set, but did not take effect

Tags: java

I set the timeout on the socket, which is valid if the value is less than 21 seconds, and after 21 seconds, I find that the timeout is still 21 seconds

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        String time1= sdf.format(new Date());
        System.out.println(time1);
        try {
            Socket sock = new Socket();
            SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("128.28.28.28",80);
            sock.connect(socketAddress,60000);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            time1= sdf.format(new Date());
            System.out.println(time1);
        }
    }
```

Running this code should take 60 seconds to time out, but it does time out after about 21 seconds.But if you change that 60,000 to 5,000, you'll see that it's actually over in five seconds.I suspect the socket's default timeout is only 21 seconds, but I can't find evidence.I want to find the evidence and know what I should do to get him to go 60 seconds over instead of 21.

Comment: I guess the timeout comes from the server instead of the client. Can you attach the StackTrace of the thrown Exception?

Comment: Yes, this must be from the server, because this host: 128.28.28.28 is a non-existent address.My question is why I set the timeout to 60 seconds, but it was timed out in 21 seconds.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146261/i-set-the-timeout-on-the-socket-and-i-found-that-this-value-cannot-be-greater-t